How frequency of sound affects its behavior?

when a high-frequency sound and a low-frequency sound hit a solid in an incident, which one will have more refractive index?


If I am not mistaken refraction depends on the change of speed between two media. Usually in solids, high frequencies attend slightly higher frequencies than low frequencies so I guess the high frequencies will “refract slightly more”.
